# Magento and odoo latest version

Tags: magento2, windows, integration

I am new in Magento and Odoo. yesterday  I have installed Magento and odoo in **Windows 7** on localhost (XAMPP). For frontend I want to use Magento and for backend just odoo. So i found this [installation](http://odoo-magento-connector.com/) on google but it is not for Windows environment. Please somebody can tell me how can i use them both ?

More info :

- Magento  Latest version 2.1.0
- Odoo     v8.0
- xampp    v3.2.2
- Php      v7.x.

Comment: provide me help plz